# Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException on my code?

Tags: java, exception, java.util.scanner

What did i do wrong??

The errors are:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
>   at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
>   at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
>   at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
>   at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
>   at MyClass.main(MyClass.java:14)

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class MyClass {
public static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int person,ai,aiint;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
     Random rand = new Random(); 

   System.out.println("Let's Play rock paper scissors! press 1 for rock 2 for paper 3 for scissors ");
   System.out.println();
   aiint=rand.nextInt(3)+1;
   System.out.println("Enter your play: ");
    person=scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Computer play is: " +aiint);
    System.out.println("Your play is:" +person);
    if (person==aiint) {
        System.out.println("It's a tie!");
    }
    else if (person==1){
            if(aiint==2){
                System.out.println("Paper beats rock, you lose!");
            }
            else if(aiint==3){
                System.out.println("Rock beats scissors, you win!");
            }
        }
    else if (person==2){
            if(aiint==1){
                System.out.println("Paper beats rock, you win!");
            }
            else if (aiint==3){
                System.out.println("Scissors beats paper, you lose!");
            }
        }
    else if (person==3){
        if(aiint==1){
            System.out.println("Rock beats scissors, you lose!");
        }
        else if(aiint==2){
            System.out.println("Scissors beats paper. you win!");
        }
    }    
    }
}
```

Comment: Any reason you're instantiating `new Scanner(System.in)` twice?

Comment: Just tried the code myself. Works fine, aktually.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working fine.

But since you mentioned `NoSuchElementException`, it is thrown when you try to read something form the `Scanner` but the `Scanner` do not have anything to be read.

From documentation of `Scanner#nextInt()`

> @throws NoSuchElementException if input is exhausted

To prevent it you should check whether any element exists in the `Scanner`:

```
if(scan.hasNextInt()){
    person = scan.nextInt();
} else {
    //show error
    return;
}
```